# Not found URI in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-4

i have a problem with CodeIgniter 4 and i can not find the solution.

I want to order my controllers so i created a folder called Webapp. In this folder, i added the agregar-opinion controller.

[image]

As you can see, i am extending the BaseController in this class. However, i do not want that my URL looks like "example.com/webapp/agregar-opinion". I want "example.com/agregar-opinion" instead.

To do that, i added the route like that:

[image]

However, my web shows the message "404 - File Not Found" when i go to example.com/agregar-opinion. I thought my routes was wrong, but if I delete the line 3 "use App\Controllers\BaseController;" in my agregar-opinion controller, I obtain the PHP error message, advicing me that the
Class 'App\Controllers\Webapp\BaseController' not found.

[image]

So I guess it is finding my URL, so this is not the error.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem changing the namespaces.

In Routes.php:

```
$routes->group('/', ['namespace'=>'App\Controllers\Webapp'],function ($routes) {
$routes->get('specific-controller', 'specific_controller');
});
```

In my specific controller:

```
namespace App\Controllers\Webapp;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;

class Specific_Controller extends BaseController{
...
}
```

I hope this answer could help someone in the future.